# why can't i connect to postgres on AWS EC2?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm hoping someone who has experienced this before can help me get this connection to AWS/EC2 -> Postgres working.

All the following is via terminal, on a Mac client.

The database in question - Postgres - is running remotely on this EC2 server, *not*, on my local Mac (nor is Postgres installed on my local Mac)

My understanding is that I need to be able to actually connect to the EC2 server and make an SSL "tunnel" connection -: from my PC to this same EC2 server -- so I can then, access the Postgres database

If my understanding there is wrong please let me know.

So, I have 2 terminal windows open. Terminal A, and Terminal B.

## In Terminal A

(a) connecting to the EC2 server works fine. Here's the CLI command:

`ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -i my.pem ubuntu@xx.yy.zzz.99`

The CLI in Terminal A then shows me the Ubuntu/server prompt

`Last login: Wed Oct 25 12:27:31 2017 from aaa222-444.xxxx.rrr.ff.net
ubuntu@ip-111-222-333-44:~$`

then, I go to terminal B...

## In Terminal B

(b) i try to make a connection to Postgres **from local** using the following command:

`psql -h localhost -p 3307 -U postgres_uid postgres_databasename`

THIS FAILS EVERY TIME.

**I get this response in Terminal B:**

**`psql: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: [`**

I am wondering, is there is a DIFFERENT SSL setup that is needed to make this DATABASE connection ? Or should it be that once I am logged into the AWS EC2 server (as noted above) I should be able to run psql commands (or use GUI clients like Navicat etc) ?

I'm at a loss and no one here knows how to fix this / set this up. it's probably something simple but that's fine, I just need to get connected :-)

Appreciate anyone's help with this thanks.

Comment: you config that port to connect psql? because the port by default is 5432 try with it.

Comment: i just tried: ```psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres_uid postgres_databasename```.  error returned was ```could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```

Answer (score -1):

Use URI syntax in the -d option, and the SSL should take care of itself.

I use the following command to access cloud postgres instances (on bluemix, not ec2), give it a go...:

```
psql -d postgres://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i just tried that and the same error was returned